# Find max value - Java

Tags: java, max

This program is working but not the way that I'd like.  I am able to calculate the max, but I have to first define the number of arguments.  I would like to be able to put in a variable number of arguments, then return the max.
How can I do?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner cin=new Scanner(System.in);

    int n=cin.nextInt();
    int max=cin.nextInt();
    for(int i=2; i<=n; i++){
        int num=cin.nextInt();
        if(num>max) max=num;
    }
    System.out.println(max);

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I think he's writing for 3 ex wives?

Comment: You want an conditional break? That is what my mindreading is telling me. The quick and dirty drop in solution would be to put a break statement into the for loop. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: This program working  when you add how many numbers compare each other for ex firstly write 5 and numbers 4 5 6 8 9 max is 9, but ı want to just write input for ex 4 5 6 8 9 and max is 9 would be how can

Comment: OH. Find the largest number that has been entered.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It looks like 6,1,2,3,4,5,6 should output 6, which sound like it is what you want.

Comment: n?5 numbers 1 5 4 7 8 and max is 8 but ı want to just ı write 1 5 4 7 8 without n? how can ı do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to get max without giving the number of inputs as the first argument.

1. read line as a string
2. tokenize and covert the numbers to integer (convert to float if you allow floating point numbers)
3. calc max

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner cin=new Scanner(System.in);
       String input=cin.nextLine();
       String[] numbers = input.split("\\s");
       int max = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
       for(int i=1; i<numbers.length; i++){
           int num=Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
           if(num>max) max=num;
       }
       System.out.println(max);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is my guess, you can tell me if this is what you want to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //Your tokenizer
  Scanner scanForNumbers = new Scanner(System.in);

  //First prompt for number of numbers
  System.out.print("Print the Number of Numbers to Enter:");

  int numberOfNumbers = scanForNumbers.nextInt();

  System.out.println();

  int maxOfNumbers = 0;

  int tempNum = 0;
  //making number of numbers the max iterate till you get there. 
  for(int index = 0 index < numberOfNumbers; index++){
    //Prompt for a number
    System.out.print("Enter another Number");
    tempNum = scanForNumbers.nextInt();

    System.out.println();
    //if it is bigger, set a new max.  
    if(tempNum > maxOfNumbers){

        maxOfNumbers = tempNum;

    }

  }
  System.out.println("The Bigger Number is : " + maxOfNumbers);
}
```

Comment: My code is like that but ı want to without numberOfnumbers just ı write input for ex 5 7 8 9 6 and max is 9 how can ı do